# vue, v-for, how to void dublicate data by read only first index in array?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

V-for bring me same data three times because JSON has it in three different languages.

```
Phone: 0400 123456 0 
Phone: 0400 123456 1 
Phone: 0400 123456 2 

<ul v-for ="(contactDetail, index) in result.contactDetails"
  v-bind:key="index">
  <li>Phone: {{ contactDetail.value }} {{ index }}  </li>
</ul>
```

Q) how to check if index is bigger than 0 and only return first one.

looks like vue is complaining that "vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for"

Thanks MikroMike

Comment: did you try computed prop? and by `index > 0 and only return the first one` you mean?

Comment: no, haven't tried. Not sure how to do it.
I have tried to v-if inside v-for, that did not work.

tried to count if index is bigger than zero, but did not work either.

Comment: check the following link https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html you can return a filtered array based on `result.contactDetails` which fits your criteria and use it in render

Comment: Thanks, I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data will always be an array, you can just take only the first element using slice. This way, regardless of how many elements there are, you will only ever show the first one.

```
<ul v-for ="(contactDetail, index) in result.contactDetails.slice(0, 1)"
  v-bind:key="index">
  <li>Phone: {{ contactDetail.value }} {{ index }}</li>
</ul>
```